# iMessage sending to my mac and phone

Tags: mac, messages

I am receving messages from my phone to my mac and I would like to turn it off, can anyone help? I am new to mac and really just can understand how to make my messages go to my phone and mac I would like it in just my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Go to messages (if you can't find it anywhere just hit command+space bar and search for messages). When messages opens up hit Messages again. It's a the top of the left of your screen next to the Apple logo. Hit preferences, and hit Accounts. You should see that you are signed in. Just hit your account and hit sign out. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Messages app on your Mac and choose Messages menu > Preferences. Click on the Accounts tab, then click on your Apple ID on the left. Choose Sign Out on the right.

Note that by doing this, you can no longer send iMessages from your Mac.